# Silverlight Childwindow + Implicit Style not working

Tags: silverlight-4.0, coding-style, childwindow

Using Silverlight 4, we can't seem to get Childwindows' to show our implicit styles.  Every other control on our app takes the implicit styles but the childwindow (even the controls on the childwindow take their implicit styles)

(we are using the toolkit styles)

```
<!--ChildWindow-->
<Style TargetType="controls:ChildWindow">
    <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="false"/>
    <Setter Property="TabNavigation" Value="Cycle"/>
    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush">
        <Setter.Value>
            <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                <GradientStop Color="#FFA3AEB9" Offset="0"/>
                <GradientStop Color="#FF8399A9" Offset="0.375"/>
                <GradientStop Color="#FF718597" Offset="0.375"/>
                <GradientStop Color="#FF617584" Offset="1"/>
            </LinearGradientBrush>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="OverlayBrush" Value="#7F000000"/>
    <Setter Property="OverlayOpacity" Value="1"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="controls:ChildWindow">
                <Grid x:Name="Root">
                    <Grid.Resources>
                        <Style x:Key="CloseButtonStyle" TargetType="Button">
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FF1F3B53"/>
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FF000000"/>
                            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="3"/>
                            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                                        <GradientStop Color="#FFA3AEB9" Offset="0"/>
                                        <GradientStop Color="#FF8399A9" Offset="0.375"/>
                                        <GradientStop Color="#FF718597" Offset="0.375"/>
                                        <GradientStop Color="#FF617584" Offset="1"/>
                                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                            <Setter Property="Template">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                                        <Grid x:Name="grid" Height="14" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="15" Background="#02FFFFFF">
                                            <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                                    <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                                                    <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver">
                                                        <Storyboard>
                                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="X_Fuzz2" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Visible"/>
                                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="X_Fuzz1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Visible"/>
                                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="X_Fuzz0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Visible"/>
                                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                            <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetName="X" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="0.95"/>
                                                        </Storyboard>
                                                    </VisualState>
                                                    <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                                        <Storyboard>
                                                            <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetName="X" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="0.85"/>
                                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="X_Fuzz2" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Visible"/>
                                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="X_Fuzz1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Visible"/>
                                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="X_Fuzz0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Visible"/>
                                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                        </Storyboard>
                                                    </VisualState>
                                                    <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                                        <Storyboard>
                                                            <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetName="X" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="0.5"/>
                                                        </Storyboard>
                                                    </VisualState>
                                                </VisualStateGroup>
                                            </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                            <Path x:Name="X_Fuzz2" Fill="#14C51900" Stretch="Fill" Stroke="#14C51900" Height="8" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,-1,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="9" Opacity="1" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Visibility="Collapsed" Data="F1 M 6.742676,3.852539 L 9.110840,1.559570 L 8.910645,0.500000 L 6.838379,0.500000 L 4.902832,2.435547 L 2.967285,0.500000 L 0.895020,0.500000 L 0.694824,1.559570 L 3.062988,3.852539 L 0.527832,6.351563 L 0.689941,7.600586 L 2.967285,7.600586 L 4.897949,5.575195 L 6.854004,7.600586 L 9.115723,7.600586 L 9.277832,6.351563 L 6.742676,3.852539 Z">
                                                <Path.RenderTransform>
                                                    <TransformGroup>
                                                        <ScaleTransform ScaleX="1.3" ScaleY="1.3"/>
                                                    </TransformGroup>
                                                </Path.RenderTransform>
                                            </Path>
                                            <Path x:Name="X_Fuzz1" Fill="#1EC51900" Stretch="Fill" Stroke="#1EC51900" Height="8" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,-1,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="9" Opacity="1" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Visibility="Collapsed" Data="F1 M 6.742676,3.852539 L 9.110840,1.559570 L 8.910645,0.500000 L 6.838379,0.500000 L 4.902832,2.435547 L 2.967285,0.500000 L 0.895020,0.500000 L 0.694824,1.559570 L 3.062988,3.852539 L 0.527832,6.351563 L 0.689941,7.600586 L 2.967285,7.600586 L 4.897949,5.575195 L 6.854004,7.600586 L 9.115723,7.600586 L 9.277832,6.351563 L 6.742676,3.852539 Z">
                                                <Path.RenderTransform>
                                                    <TransformGroup>
                                                        <ScaleTransform ScaleX="1.1" ScaleY="1.1"/>
                                                    </TransformGroup>
                                                </Path.RenderTransform>
                                            </Path>
                                            <Path x:Name="X_Fuzz0" Fill="#FFC51900" Stretch="Fill" Stroke="#FFC51900" Height="8" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,-1,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="9" Opacity="1" Visibility="Collapsed" Data="F1 M 6.742676,3.852539 L 9.110840,1.559570 L 8.910645,0.500000 L 6.838379,0.500000 L 4.902832,2.435547 L 2.967285,0.500000 L 0.895020,0.500000 L 0.694824,1.559570 L 3.062988,3.852539 L 0.527832,6.351563 L 0.689941,7.600586 L 2.967285,7.600586 L 4.897949,5.575195 L 6.854004,7.600586 L 9.115723,7.600586 L 9.277832,6.351563 L 6.742676,3.852539 Z"/>
                                            <Path x:Name="X" Fill="#FFFFFFFF" Stretch="Fill" Height="8" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,-1,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="9" Opacity="0.7" Data="F1 M 6.742676,3.852539 L 9.110840,1.559570 L 8.910645,0.500000 L 6.838379,0.500000 L 4.902832,2.435547 L 2.967285,0.500000 L 0.895020,0.500000 L 0.694824,1.559570 L 3.062988,3.852539 L 0.527832,6.351563 L 0.689941,7.600586 L 2.967285,7.600586 L 4.897949,5.575195 L 6.854004,7.600586 L 9.115723,7.600586 L 9.277832,6.351563 L 6.742676,3.852539 Z">
                                                <Path.Stroke>
                                                    <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                                                        <GradientStop Color="#FF313131" Offset="1"/>
                                                        <GradientStop Color="#FF8E9092" Offset="0"/>
                                                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                                                </Path.Stroke>
                                            </Path>
                                        </Grid>
                                    </ControlTemplate>
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                        </Style>
                    </Grid.Resources>
                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="WindowStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Open">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="0" Storyboard.TargetName="Overlay" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity">
                                        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0"/>
                                        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.3" Value="1"/>
                                    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="0" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentRoot" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(RenderTransform).(Children)[0].ScaleX">
                                        <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0"/>
                                        <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.25" Value="0"/>
                                        <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.4" Value="1"/>
                                        <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeySpline="0,0,0.5,1" KeyTime="00:00:00.45" Value="1.05"/>
                                        <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.55" Value="1"/>
                                    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="0" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentRoot" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(RenderTransform).(Children)[0].ScaleY">
                                        <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0"/>
                                        <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.25" Value="0"/>
                                        <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.4" Value="1"/>
                                        <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeySpline="0,0,0.5,1" KeyTime="00:00:00.45" Value="1.05"/>
                                        <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.55" Value="1"/>
                                    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Closed">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="0" Storyboard.TargetName="Overlay" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity">
                                        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="1"/>
                                        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.3" Value="0"/>
                                    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="0" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentRoot" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(RenderTransform).(Children)[0].ScaleX">
                                        <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.2" Value="1"/>
                                        <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.25" Value="1.05"/>
                                        <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.45" Value="0"/>
                                    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="0" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentRoot" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(RenderTransform).(Children)[0].ScaleY">
                                        <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.2" Value="1"/>
                                        <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.25" Value="1.05"/>
                                        <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.45" Value="0"/>
                                    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <Grid x:Name="Overlay" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Opacity="{TemplateBinding OverlayOpacity}" Background="{TemplateBinding OverlayBrush}"/>
                    <Grid x:Name="ContentRoot" Height="{TemplateBinding Height}" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalAlignment}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalAlignment}" Width="{TemplateBinding Width}" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
                        <Grid.RenderTransform>
                            <TransformGroup>
                                <ScaleTransform/>
                                <SkewTransform/>
                                <RotateTransform/>
                                <TranslateTransform/>
                            </TransformGroup>
                        </Grid.RenderTransform>
                        <Border HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="-1" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Background="#14000000" BorderBrush="#14000000" BorderThickness="1" CornerRadius="2"/>
                        <Border HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="-2" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Background="#0F000000" BorderBrush="#0F000000" BorderThickness="1" CornerRadius="2.25"/>
                        <Border HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="-3" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Background="#0C000000" BorderBrush="#0C000000" BorderThickness="1" CornerRadius="2.5"/>
                        <Border HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="-4" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Background="#0A000000" BorderBrush="#0A000000" BorderThickness="1" CornerRadius="2.75"/>
                        <Border BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" CornerRadius="2">
                            <Border.Background>
                                <SolidColorBrush Color="#FF262626"/>
                            </Border.Background>
                            <Border Margin="1" CornerRadius="1.5">
                                <Border.Background>
                                    <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                                        <GradientStop Color="{StaticResource ExpressionBottomGradientBrush2}" Offset="1"/>
                                        <GradientStop Color="{StaticResource ExpressionBottomGradientBrush4}" Offset="0"/>
                                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                                </Border.Background>
                                <Grid>
                                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                        <RowDefinition/>
                                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <Border x:Name="Chrome" Width="Auto" BorderThickness="0,0,0,1">
                                        <Border.BorderBrush>
                                            <SolidColorBrush Color="{StaticResource ExpressionBottomGradientBrush1}"/>
                                        </Border.BorderBrush>
                                        <Border.Background>
                                            <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,0.527999997138977" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                                                <GradientStop Color="{StaticResource ExpressionBottomGradientBrush1}" Offset="1"/>
                                                <GradientStop Color="{StaticResource ExpressionBottomGradientBrush2}" Offset="0"/>
                                                <GradientStop Color="{StaticResource ExpressionBottomGradientBrush2}" Offset="0.356"/>
                                            </LinearGradientBrush>
                                        </Border.Background>
                                        <Grid Height="Auto" Width="Auto">
                                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                <ColumnDefinition/>
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="30"/>
                                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                            <ContentControl FontWeight="Bold" IsTabStop="False" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="6,0,6,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" Content="{TemplateBinding Title}">
                                                <ContentControl.Foreground>
                                                    <SolidColorBrush Color="{StaticResource TextColor}"/>
                                                </ContentControl.Foreground>
                                            </ContentControl>
                                            <Button x:Name="CloseButton" IsTabStop="False" Height="14" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Style="{StaticResource CloseButtonStyle}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="15" Grid.Column="1"/>
                                        </Grid>
                                    </Border>
                                    <Border Margin="7" Grid.Row="1" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                                        <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentPresenter" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}"/>
                                    </Border>
                                </Grid>
                            </Border>
                        </Border>
                    </Grid>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

.. And here is the xaml being used.

```
<controls:ChildWindow x:Class="CommonModule.Views.OptionsWindowView"
       xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
       xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
       xmlns:commands="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Practices.Prism.Commands;assembly=Microsoft.Practices.Prism"
       xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls;assembly=System.Windows.Controls"
       xmlns:regions="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Practices.Prism.Regions;assembly=Microsoft.Practices.Prism"
       Width="400" Height="300" 
       Title="Options"
       HasCloseButton="False">
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Margin="2">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <controls:TabControl BorderThickness="5"
                         x:Name="OptionsTabRegion"
                         regions:RegionManager.RegionName="OptionsTabRegion">
        <regions:TabControlRegionAdapter.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style BasedOn="{StaticResource TabItemStyle}" TargetType="controls:TabItem">
                <Setter Property="HeaderTemplate">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </regions:TabControlRegionAdapter.ItemContainerStyle>
    </controls:TabControl>

    <Button x:Name="CancelButton" Content="Cancel" commands:Click.Command="{Binding CancelCommand}" Click="CancelButton_Click" Width="75" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,12,0,0" Grid.Row="1"/>
    <Button x:Name="OKButton" Content="OK" commands:Click.Command="{Binding OkCommand}" Click="OKButton_Click" Width="75" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,12,79,0" Grid.Row="1" />
</Grid>
```

Comment: can you post your childwindow implicit style?

Answer (score 1):

This would appear to be an issue with Silverlight 4 in that the default style key is not set to the `typeof(ChildWindow)`.

Either inherit your own class from "ChildWindow" and in the constructor set the following:

`DefaultStyleKey = typeof(MyChildWindow);`

Or alternatively use an explicit style by creating a "key" and applying that style key on the childwindow control.

Answer (score 0):

```
Color="{StaticResource ExpressionBottomGradientBrush2}"
```

please note that if ExpressionBottomGradientBrush2 is defined as a System.Windows.Media.SolidColorBrush, you can't set it to System.Windows.Media.Color.

If you have any errors in your child window's style, it just won't apply, I guess that's the reason you can't see it. :)

Comment: Good eye, but that brush is actually a color (straight from the toolkit)

Comment: what exactly is this toolkit style? which theme are you using?

Comment: Expression Dark 
http://silverlight.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Silverlight%20Toolkit%20Overview%20Part%203

Comment: did you actually extract all the styles from expression dark theme? do you mind showing me the brush resources used in the child window?

Comment: They aren't used in the child window, the styles are applied implicitly.